# Why Django Rest API id not in order?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

So, I have django rest api with model like

```
class Data(models.Model):
node_id = models.ForeignKey("Node", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
vibration = models.IntegerField()
moisture = models.IntegerField()
gps_latitude = models.CharField(max_length=250)
gps_longitude = models.CharField(max_length=250)
gyro_x = models.FloatField()
gyro_y = models.FloatField()
gyro_z = models.FloatField()
accelero_x = models.FloatField()
accelero_y = models.FloatField()
accelero_z = models.FloatField()
displacement = models.IntegerField()
```

The serializer is like this:

```
class DataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Data
    fields = '__all__'
```

And the views is like this :

```
class DataViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Data.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DataSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]                              
    filterset_fields = ['node_id']
```

You can access my api on : https://gmlews.com/api/data/

The problem is my id on the web page won't come in order. I receive all the data from raspberry pi. Where the problem come from? the code from raspberry or my django rest code?

After id 253, it come id 255,257,259. It should be id 254 and so on in order. How can I handle this id to be in order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add an `ordering` field in the `Meta` of your model :

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["id"]
```